# How to make fade in on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some text fade in over an image on hover over the div container. Just to give you a precise example here is what I'm looking for: http://outgrow.me/.

Here is my HTML as it stands:

```
<div class="project-boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <a href="project1.html">
                    <img src="../img/project1.png">
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="project1.html">
                    <img src="../img/project1.png">
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="project1.html">
                    <img src="../img/project1.png">
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="project1.html">
                    <img src="../img/project1.png">
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </a>
            </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/**********************
*****PROJECT BOXES*****
**********************/
.project-boxes {
    margin: 0 3%;
}

.box {
    padding: 2.5%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 2% 3.9999999999999999999%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #BABABA;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box h3 {
    color: #3F7250;
}
```

I don't have any javascript or jquery for this yet but would like to implement some in my project. Feel free to share this with me on a fiddle or something. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in fade out on image hover using CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375724/fade-in-fade-out-on-image-hover-using-css3)

Comment: I am looking for a solution using javascript.

Comment: @TomFinet why using JS if it can be done in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to target the hover event and fade in the description.

```js
$('.box a').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.desc').fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.desc').fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box .desc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="project1.html">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <div class="desc">
      <h3>Project 1</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9a9aetn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

No need for JS. Use plain CSS and `:hover`

```
 /* SIMPLY ADD THIS TO YOUR CSS */

.box img ~ *{                  
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.box:hover img ~ *{  
  opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.project-boxes {
  margin: 0 3%;
}
.box {
  padding: 2.5%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 2% 3.9999999999999999999%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #BABABA;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.box h3 {
  color: #3F7250;
}

.box img ~ *{                   /* ADD THIS */
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.box:hover img ~ *{             /* AND THIS */
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="project1.html">
      <img src="../img/project1.png">
      <h3>Project 1</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="project1.html">
      <img src="../img/project1.png">
      <h3>Project 1</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="project1.html">
      <img src="../img/project1.png">
      <h3>Project 1</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="project1.html">
      <img src="../img/project1.png">
      <h3>Project 1</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery:

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="project1.html">
     <div class='text'>
        <h3>Project 1</h3>
        <p>Description</p>
     </div>
     <img src="../img/project1.png">
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.box .text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index = 1;
}

.box img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index = 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.box img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing this on javascript would be more complicated that to [do it with jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp) or CSS.
but, still if you want javascript so badly here :

```js
// fade out

function fadeOut(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;

  (function fade() {
    if ((el.style.opacity -= .1) < 0) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      el.classList.add('is-hidden');
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}

// fade in

function fadeIn(el, display) {
  if (el.classList.contains('is-hidden')) {
    el.classList.remove('is-hidden');
  }
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.display = display || "block";

  (function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}

var btn = document.querySelector('.js-btn');
var el = document.querySelector('.js-fade');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (el.classList.contains('is-hidden')) {
    fadeIn(el);
  } else {
    fadeOut(el);
  }
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span class="js-btn btn">Click me</span>
<div class='js-fade is-hidden'>You look amazing!</div>
```

Comment: **jQuery has it's own Docs** for it's [fadeIn Method](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/), but you linked to the W3Schools?? Even providing a super complicated code that has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: what's wrong with W3School? and the OP wanted a javascript solution... this just shows how it can be done using to functions... OP can easily manipulate the code to get a hover action.

Comment: easy there... I just started out and w3schools works fine for me(my online instructors always use w3)...and in your code you just toggle display... no fade-in.